# How do you set a relative date in windows RAR command line?

Tags: rar

Right now I'm using command-line RAR in windows to zip up old files.

I'm using the -tb switch to tell rar to zip up all files before a certain date/time.

But it has to be like this: -tb2015-01-01

Is there a way of specifying "anything earlier than 3 days ago"?

Comment: Could you specify which program you are using? Windows doesn't have native support for RAR.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about switch -tb, I assume you are using WinRAR.

**WinRAR** has another command line switch `-TO<time>` for processing files older than the specified time. The `<time>` is specified in format `[<ndays>d][<nhours>h][<nminutes>m][<nseconds>s]` so "anything earlier than 3 days ago" would be `-to3d`

In **7-Zip** and other programs where you don't have direct switch for this you could use forfiles, e.g.

```
forfiles /d -3 /c "cmd /c 7za a -t7z archivename.7z @file"
```